# Know Socket.io event name when handling an error on NestJS WebSocketGateway

Tags: typescript, websocket, error-handling, socket.io, nestjs

Let's say I have the following `WebSocketGateway` in NestJS

```
@WebSocketGateway()
export class MyWsGateway {
  @SubscribeMessage('my-event')
  @UserFilters(new MyWsExceptionFilter())
  create(@MessageBody() body: any) {
    throw new WsException('Forced error');
  }
}
```

At this point I want to customize the response to the client when an error occurs so I have implemented my own WsExceptionFilter based on [NestJS official code](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/websockets/exceptions/base-ws-exception-filter.ts) (note this code is simplified):

```
@Catch(WsException)
export class MyWsExceptionFilter extends BaseWsExceptionFilter {
  handleError<TClient extends { emit: Function }>(
    client: TClient,
    exception: WsException
  ) {
    const message = {status: 'error', message: exception.getError()};
    client.emit('here-is-where-i-would-like-to-set-the-event-name', message);
  }
}
```

As you can see on the implementation of `BaseWsExceptionFilter` the response of the error is emited through event 'exception'. This is not valid for my case, though.

After long time searching on the Internet and surfing in NestJS's code, I haven't been able to find a way to get/know the input event name where the error was thrown.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Nestjs attach metadata on function using decorators, including the event name you are looking for.
You can access those metadata using `Reflect.getMetadata(...)`.

So if you have a reference to the event handler method wich throw the exception you can get the message name like this :
`const messageName = Reflect.getMetadata("message", methodReference)`

To get the reference to the handler method, you can use a nestjs interceptor.

```js
async intercept(context, next) {
    return next.handle().pipe(tap({
        error: (err)=> {
            err.eventName = Reflect.getMetadata(
                'message', 
                (context.switchToWs() as any).handler
            )
        }
    })
}
```

Then in your exception filter, you can access the event name !